# How can I dynamically add a new menu item to the beginning of a specific WordPress menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, wp-nav-menu-item

I have 4 menus registered within my WordPress theme.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'honeycomb' ),
    'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Mobile Cat Products', 'honeycomb' ),
    'menu-3' => esc_html__( 'Top Bar', 'honeycomb' ),
    'menu-4' => esc_html__( 'Shopify Nav', 'honeycomb' ),
) );
```

I need to dynamically insert a new menu link at the **beginning** of menu-4 From what I understand its possible to filter a specific menu using a variant of wp_nav_menu_items by simply passing in the theme location name of the menu. In my case 'menu-4'.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_menu-4_items', 'prefix_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );

function prefix_add_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
   $items .=  '<li class="menu-item">My New Item Here</li>';

   return $items;
}
```

However this is not working. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$menu->slug` here `apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args );` is not the nav menu id... it's the Menu Name slug... like here i have named my Menu as `Main Menu` so the slug becomes `main-menu` so your filter would be...

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_main-menu_items', 'so68759013_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );

function so68759013_add_menu_item( $items, $args )
{   
  $items .=  '<li class="menu-item">My New Item Here</li>';

  return $items;
}
```

[image: Menu]